# PID controller making use of the Message type sensor_msgs/JointState

Tags: control, ros, pid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys
I am looking for at PID controller which is capable of understand the message type sensor_msgs/JointState.
As far i can see those which are available uses a custom message type, but none which uses  the sensor_msg/JointState
.. Do any of you know one??

I've looked into some, and http://wiki.ros.org/pid  and seems to be what I am looking with the exception of the message type being not the one i want..
Somebody who are able to convert it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209807/pid-controller-making-use-of-the-message-type-sensor_msgs/jointstate/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wikipedia already provides pseudo code..

---

Originally posted by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) with karma: 156 on 2015-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any open implementation, but if you can tolerate the added latency of one additional hop though a ros node, you can write a very simple forwarding node that subscribes to a `sensor_msgs/JointState` topic, and publishes to the ROS interface of whatever controller you have otherwise found suitable.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-05-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1